# how to recognize external sd card mounted in the device and that device also have internal sd card?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))            
{           
    System.out.println("​sd card present");         
}
```

by using this code i am able to find the sd card but i am unable recognize which sd card it was. that is inbuilt sd or external...

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-t/557831-am-i-saving-sdcard-not.html plz refer this link once.....

On the **SGS2 Samsung** has a 2 GB partition for the system and the remaining 14 GB partitioned and recognized as an sd card by making its mount point /sdcard. Along with that we can mount an external removable sd card in that device. Then how to recognize external removable sd card through programming.

Comment: There is no standard API.  You would have to look for a vendor extension, or troll through /proc/mounts looking for likely candidates - removable cards (or at least partitions on them you should consider using) are likely to be some variant of a FAT filesystem (but get the primary external storage from the API - on MTP devices that is not FAT).  Or just let advanced users browse the whole device and pick a location.

Comment: Will this work [`public static boolean isExternalStorageRemovable ()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable%28%29)? @ChrisStratton

Comment: Assuming it does what it's name implies, how will that help you?  It would refer only to the official (ie, primary) external storage.  I suppose it might tell you not to bother looking for alternatives - though one could conceive of a tablet with an sdcard slot as it's "external storage" that also had vendor support for mounting usb thumb drives.

Comment: @ChrisStratton :thank you for giving me response.................... my original requirement is to copy some files into external sd card i.e removable sd card. how to find the path of removable sd card not the external unremovable sd card...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sdcardpath = null;
    File[] faFiles = new File("/mnt").listFiles();
    abc: {
        for (File file : faFiles) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String pathMain = "" + file.getAbsolutePath();
                Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "222222222222" + pathMain);
                if (pathMain.indexOf("ext") > 0&&pathMain.startsWith("/mnt/")) {
                    File fp = new File(pathMain);
                    if (fp.canWrite()) {
                        Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "33333333333333333"
                                + pathMain);
                        //external sd card is there..
                        sdcardpath = pathMain;
                        break abc;
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                } else {
                    if (pathMain.indexOf("sd") > 0) {
                        File fp = new File(pathMain);
                        if (fp.canWrite()) {
                            Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "33333333333333333"+ pathMain);
                            sdcardpath = pathMain;

                               //internal sd card is there..
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i donot know whether it is correct way or not but i do like this it is working for me..

Comment: Nope... I've seen devices that put the extra sdcard under / rather than under /mnt